# How to measure and increase instance connection times for Durable functions

Tags: python, azure, data-binding, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I am trying to measure the connection time to an instance connecting to an external service with the Durable function.

Is the following code correctly measuring the startup time and connection time of the instance?
Also, if I connect to more external services, does the connection time to the instance increase even in the warm state?

```
import azure.functions as func
import azure.durable_functions as df
import logging
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time

app = df.DFApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
@app.route(route="orchestrators/client_function")
@app.durable_client_input(client_name="client")
async def client_function(req: func.HttpRequest, client: df.DurableOrchestrationClient) -> func.HttpResponse:
    instance_id = await client.start_new("orchestrator", None)
    logging.info(f"Started orchestration with ID = '{instance_id}'.")
    await client.wait_for_completion_or_create_check_status_response(req, instance_id)
    status = await client.get_status(instance_id)
    return f"runtime: {status.runtime_status}\n\noutput:\n {status.output}" 

@app.orchestration_trigger(context_name="context")
def orchestrator(context: df.DurableOrchestrationContext):
    start = time.perf_counter()
    test = yield context.call_activity('main', {"start": start})    
    return "Test"

@app.blob_output(arg_name="outputblob",
                path="newblob/test.txt",
                connection="BlobStorageConnection")
@app.activity_trigger(input_name="time")
def  main(time: dict, outputblob: func.Out[str]):
    start_up_time = time.perf_counter() - time["start"]
    return  {"start_up_time": start_up_time}
```

Answer (score 0):

> if I connect to more external services, does the connection time to the instance increase even in the warm state?

Definitely,

1. Each external service that you connect, may have its own latency. The combined latency of these external services calls can add up.
2. As Durable functions runs activities in parallel , it does more simultaneous connection attempts to the external services - that potentially increases the total connection time.
3. **In a warm state**, there are many resources might be available because Azure Functions runs on a serverless, it means resources are allocated dynamically on demand. So, if you exceed the concurrency limit, your function executions might be delayed by increasing the connection time for each.
   Check the hosting plan of your Azure functions that has concurrency limit details.
4. If those external services has any limit of requests handling within a given time frame, then you might experience delays.